# How can I get the diameter of each community

Tags: python, igraph, graph-theory

I am trying to calculate the diameter of each community in my dataset (Zachary's karate club) on jupyter. I created a loop to iterate through but it gives me the diameter of the whole network rather than of each community

```
from igraph import *
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('zachary.txt',sep =" ", header = None)
data_values = data.values
g = Graph()
new_data = data_values.tolist()
data_graph = g.Adjacency(new_data, mode = 'undirected')
s = data_graph.community_infomap()
print(s)
s_List = list(s)
print(s_List)
for ic in s_List:
    y = data_graph.diameter(ic)
    print(y)
```

I expect the output to be like "1,2,2" or "1,3,1" but the actual output is "5,5,5", which is the diameter of the whole community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first consider the subgraph induced by the community before taking the diameter.  I believe replacing your definitely of y with this should work:

```
y = data_graph.subgraph(ic).diameter()
```